# How to ignore routing error with wrong verb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few POST actions. There are always stupid crawlers trying to ping those actions, resulting in "No route matches [GET]" errors.

There are too much of them, and most of them are purely noise. How can I make it so this kind of error messages are ignored.

I used to use exception_notification gem, and now I use rollbar gem. The amount of these kind of trash error message always floods my error monitoring (either lots of messages, or too much error api calls).

Comment: You should just block such crawlers.

Comment: Don't have time to add ip addresses all the time